# Why does my Docker mount secret not show in the container /run/secrets?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to pass a secret file inside of a Dockerfile. The docker build is successful but the secret file is not getting copied inside the container.

**Directory:**

```
~/dockerfiles$ tree -a
.
└── colorapp
    ├── .env
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── index.html

1 directory, 3 files
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
`~/dockerfiles/colorapp$ cat Dockerfile
#syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.4

FROM nginx:stable

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html

#RUN --mount=type=secret,id=_env,dst=/run/secrets/.env
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=_env,required ls -la /run/secrets/`
```

**Build Command:**

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=_env,src=.env .
```

**Build Command:**

```
:~/dockerfiles/colorapp$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=_env,src=.env .
```

```
[+] Building 5.8s (14/14) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                 0.0s
 => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.4                                                    3.4s
 => [auth] docker/dockerfile:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                0.0s
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.4@sha256:9ba7531bd80fb0a858632727cf7a112fbfd19b17e94c4  0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:stable                                                 2.1s
 => [auth] library/nginx:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 31B                                                                                0.0s
 => [stage-0 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:stable@sha256:fc5f5fb7574755c306aaf88456ebfbe0b006420a184d52b92  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0 2/3] COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-0 3/3] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=_env,required ls -la /run/secrets/                          0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                          0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                         0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:83e5670fad2db682099f0efc1468a64709ac16966a61dbce365d26a8cc23595a
```

**Scenario #2 with CAT**

```
 :~/dockerfiles/colorapp$ cat Dockerfile
    #syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.4
    
    FROM nginx:stable
    
    SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
    
    COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html
    
    #RUN --mount=type=secret,id=_env,dst=/run/secrets/.env
    RUN --mount=type=secret,id=_env,dst=/etc/secrets/.env cat /etc/secrets/.env


:~/dockerfiles/colorapp$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --secret id=_env,src=.env .
    [+] Building 2.1s (12/12) FINISHED
     => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
     => => transferring dockerfile: 38B                                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
     => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
     => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
     => resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.4                                                                                                                                                  0.9s
     => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.4@sha256:9ba7531bd80fb0a858632727cf7a112fbfd19b17e94c4e84ced81e24ef1a0dbc                                                                             0.0s
     => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
     => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
     => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:stable                                                                                                                                               0.9s
     => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
     => => transferring context: 31B                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
     => [stage-0 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:stable@sha256:fc5f5fb7574755c306aaf88456ebfbe0b006420a184d52b923d2f0197108f6b7                                                                                 0.0s
     => CACHED [stage-0 2/3] COPY index.html /usr/share/nginx/html                                                                                                                                                0.0s
     => CACHED [stage-0 3/3] RUN --mount=type=secret,id=_env,dst=/etc/secrets/.env cat /etc/secrets/.env                                                                                                          0.0s
     => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
     => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
     => => writing image sha256:79ea7a1e8c16c113d241fef5047ca7cefb4aca5818b6961ab74afb5c5045283d                                                                                                                  0.0s


    :~/dockerfiles/colorapp$ docker run -d 79ea7a1e8c16c113d241fef5047ca7cefb4aca5818b6961ab74afb5c5045283d
    fe7860115975f47b8671454a6f57abf758847489cbd2a584aa22524396899dcc


    :~/dockerfiles/colorapp$ docker exec -it fe7860115975f47b8671454a6f57abf758847489cbd2a584aa22524396899dcc /bin/bash


    root@fexxxxxxxxx:/# ls /etc/secrets/*
    ls: cannot access '/etc/secrets/*': No such file or directory

    root@fexxxxxxxxx:/# ls -la /etc/secrets/
    total 12
    drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 31 11:57 .
    drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Mar 31 11:58 ..
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing when you run the image; what behavior do you expect?  A major reason to use `RUN --mount=type=secret` is that the secret _isn't_ persisted in the image.

Comment: I want the secrets to be available inside the container under /run/secrets so that I can use them as an env variable in the container

Comment: You can't do that without using `ENV` or `COPY` (or in this case `RUN cat`) to persist the secret in the image, at which point it can be easily retrieved by anyone who has a copy of the image and it isn't especially secret any more.

Comment: @DavidMaze It still doesn't show up after using CAT. Updated Scenario #2 above.

Comment: I encounter the same issue, using `cat` or `ls`, those (temporary) files are not there.

Comment: the secret is only available in this layer: `RUN --mount=type=secret,id=_env,dst=/etc/secrets/.env ...`, outside of that it won't exist. In Scenario #2, because it's cached, you should build with `--no-cache` in order to trigger that line.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you describe is absolutely correct.  `RUN --mount=...` options only persist for the lifetime of their specific `RUN` command.  A very specific goal of `RUN --mount=secret=...` is that the secret is *not* persisted in the image.

There's a long-standing security-adjacent concern that Docker image contents are not especially protected.  If you use an `ENV` statement to set an environment variable with a password, that shows up in `docker inspect` output; if you try to store them in files, you can find them in a `docker export` tarball or (usually) print them out with commands like `docker run --entrypoint /bin/cat imagename /root/.env`.

So: you should not expect to pass credentials into `docker build` and have them available at `docker run` time.

In your example you show a file named `.env`.  You need to pass its values when you run the container, not when you build the image.  If it's a simple enough syntax that Docker can directly use it, you can set its values as environment variables

```bash
docker run --env-file=.env ...
```

Or, if it's a more complex file format but your application includes a library to read it, you can inject it as a file

```bash
docker run -v "$PWD/.env:/app/.env" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you're using `dst=` instead of `target=` in the RUN statement. I know I've seen examples using `dst` but the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/#secret) don't show it. Also I use `docker buildx build` as per that doc page.